# The existence of a type of dense subsequence of every dense sequence of eventually zero functions in $\omega^\omega$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, the-baire-space

Let $G=\{g_n: n \in \omega\}\subseteq \omega^\omega $ where $g_n$ is eventually equal to zero. Clearly $G$ is dense in  $\omega^\omega$. Suppose that $Q=\{q_n:n \in \omega\}\subseteq G$ is also dense.

**Question:** Does there exists a subsequence $Q'=\{q_{n_v}:v \in \omega\}\subseteq Q$ such that $(\forall u\geq n_v)(q_{n_v}(u)=0)$ and $(\forall v \in \omega)(q_{n_{v+1}}\mid n_v=0)$?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you say that "clearly $G$ is dense"?

Comment: I think the idea is that $G$ is the set of *all* eventually zero sequences.

Comment: Did you mean $ (\forall v\in\omega)(q_n_(v+1)\mid n_v = 0) $  (the plus 1 is in the most down subscript in my fomula)?

Comment: Hello, is a mistake and I corrected.

Comment: The first condition also seems peculiar to me. I think you can find a sequence in G s.t. $ q_n(n) \ne 0 $ for all n, and then there is no subsequence satisfing the first condition